# Sorting the contents of one list via the contents of another (Python)

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have two lists which have been created by .csv files.  The first consists of a branch id number and a list of corresponding flows.  The second is the order in which I wish to have the branche ids and their corrsponding flows sorted.  They are as follows:

```
branch_flows = [['1234-2321-1', [55, 76, 3, 55, 6]],
                ['1546-2645-1', [4, 6, 56, 3, 4]],
                // ...
                ['4123-1234-1', [6, 12, -4, 7, 9]]
               ]
```

and

```
ordered_branches = ['1234-2321-1',
                    '1234-4123-1',
                    // ...
                    '1546-2645-1']
```

I am wondering how to sort `branch_flows` the same way `ordered_branches` is ordered, but for the flows to stay related to the same ids after sorting?  The main difficulty being that some of the branch ids in `branch_flows` first two parts are reversed, but I need them to be sorted as if they were not.

e.g. looking to the lists above, desired output would be having `branch_flows` sorted in a way that the final list in `branch_flows` was placed second in the sorted list (as `1234-4123-1` in `ordered_branches` can equal both `1234-4123-1` *AND* `4123-1234-1` in `branch_list`, as the order in `branch_flows` can sometimes be the reverse of that in `ordered_branches`).

I originally tried to use dictionarys as look up tables but ran into trouble with the reading reverse order part.  Help much appreciated!

Comment: These code samples are not valid Python. Can you provide an actual dataset (or parts of it) that is usable?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker I added the '' to make the id numbers strings. Apologies. Also the "......." is just to indicate that the lists are very large.

Comment: Why the second level of `[]` in `branch_flows`?

Comment: @Tichodroma: There was no second level, there was one opening `[` too many.

Comment: @TimPietzcker ACK, thanks for the second edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to construct an appropriate `key` function to the Python `sort` function.

Ignoring the reversed-order issue, it's quite easy:

```
def key(branch):
    id, flows = branch
    return ordered_branches.index(id)
```

Considering the reversed-order issue, we can use:

```
def key(branch):
    id, flows = branch
    try:
        return ordered_branches.index(id)
    except ValueError:
        parts = id.split('-')
        id = '-'.join((parts[1], parts[0], parts[2]))
        return ordered_branches.index(id)
```

Now you can sort `branch_flows` as `sorted(branch_flows, key=key)`.

---

You can speed this up by turning `ordered_branches` into a dictionary:

```
order_dict = dict((x, i) for i, x in enumerate(ordered_branches))
```

and instead of `ordered_branches.index(id)` use `order_dict[id]` (also change `ValueError` to `KeyError`).

---

As a time-space tradeoff you could construct the reversed-order ids in the dict:

```
def reverse_id(id):
    parts = id.split('-')
    return '-'.join((parts[1], parts[0], parts[2]))
order_dict = dict((x, i) for i, x in enumerate(ordered_branches))
order_dict.update((reverse_id(x), i) for x, i in order_dict.items())
```

Now your key function just looks like:

```
def key(branch):
    id, flows = branch
    return order_dict[id]
```

Comment: thank you sincerely for taking so much time for such a detailed answer.  When I try to implement I get the following error for the line "order_dict = dict((x, i) for i, x in ordered_branches) " - too many values to unpack.  Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: @user1532369 apologies, I forgot an `enumerate` call. Fixed above.

Comment: also do you think it would be feasible to incorporate into this a line that when it detects a reverse ordered branch it multiplies it's corresponding flow values by -1?

Comment: @ ecatmur sorry I should have been clearer, I meant when I was trying to implement the original non time-space trade off piece of code, recontructing the reverse order branches is not an option for me as the branches may be used more than once in either order. i.e. some of the branches are interconnected (I am sorting line bay flow values in electrical substations).

Comment: @user1532369 that'd be best done as a separate step. You could construct a `dict` of reversed branches as above and use `if id in reversed_branches: (...)`

Comment: @ ecatmur should I add the enumerate lien to the original code? see above comment

Comment: @user1532369 yes, if constructing a `dict` with the sort order to speed things up.

Comment: I am not sure if it came across in the question but the values in ordered_flows are never reversed, only in branch_flows.

Answer (score 2):

On the surface of things, it looks as if you could do this with one dict-build and two list traversals (you already have the sorted order, after all).

Something like:

```
flow_dict = {}
for flow in branch_flow:
    # Sometimes, there's a reversal of the two parts of the key.
    key_parts = flow[0].split('-')
    flow_dict['-'.join(key_parts)] = flow
    flow_dict['-'.join([key_parts[1], key_parts[0], key_parts[2])] = flow

branch_flows = [flow_dict[key] for key in ordered_branches]
```

Building the dict should be O(n) (N inserts, each at amortized O(1)), traversing the ordered list should be O(n) and fetching the values from the dict should be O(1)). This is likely better than anything you could do by sorting.

Comment: @Vatine I get an error that split is not defined, is this for newer versions than python 2.7? Also do you think it would be poosible to implement somethign that when a reversed branch is detected its flow values can be multiplied by -1 then placed in the order of the ordered_branches?

Comment: @user1532369: My bad, it's actually a method on string objects. I've edited the code. As for modifying branch flows, I don't think that would require much in the way of changes (basically, make a small utility function that fetches a branch flow from the dict and does necessary manipulations if there's a reversed key) but the didacting value of the code is (probably) higher without it.